# Coerce logical (boolean) vector to 0 and 1

Tags: r, boolean, logical-operators, coercion

I have a numeric vector:

```
a <- 1:4
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Check if values in 'a' is larger than 2:

```
a > 2
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However, instead of `FALSE` and `TRUE`, I want my result to be expressed as `0` and `1`. Currently I am using the following method.

```
b <- (a > 2)
b[b == TRUE] <- 1
b[b == FALSE] <- 0
```

Are there any simpler methods?

Comment: `b <- ifelse(a > 2, 1, 0)`, `as.numeric(a > 2)`, `1*(a > 2)`. Take your pick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about this.

1. Using `ifelse`

   ```
   b <- ifelse(a > 2, 1, 0)
   ```

   This is just a simpler way of writing exactly what you've written in the question: if the condition returns `TRUE`, set the value to 1, otherwise set it to 0.
2. Using `as.numeric`

   ```
   b <- as.numeric(a > 2)
   ```

   Logical values can be converted to their numeric equivalents easily using this function. As one might expect, `TRUE` is set to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.
3. The lazy version of `as.numeric`

   ```
   b <- 1*(a > 2)
   ```

   When R sees the multiplication of logical values by a numeric value, it automatically coerces the logicals to their numeric equivalents. Thus logical values can be converted lazily (from a programmer's standpoint) by multiplying by 1.

Answer (score 4):

The way r codes logical data, your vector `b <- a > 2` is already (0,0,1,1) - r stores "TRUE" values as 1's and "FALSE" values as 0's. You could even take `mean(b)` and it would return .5. If you'd prefer to visualize numbers instead of logical values however, you could always just do `b <- as.numeric(b)`, or to put it all in one line of code `b <- as.numeric(a > 2)`

Comment: Technicality: In the C source, R doesn't _store_ logical values as their integer equivalents. Rather, many functions, primitives in particular, simply _treat_ logical arguments as numeric through casting.